# Separating email strings by a delimeter

Tags: ruby, email

I have an array of email addresses (roughly over 50,000) and I am interested in counting the frequency of particular email domains. For example, if I had

```
emails = [
  'Johndoe@gmail.com',
  'Johndoe@yahoo.com', 
  'Johndoe@aol.com',
  'Johndoe@someuni.xyz.com',
  'Janedoe@gmail.com'
]
```

and I am interested in which email domain appears the most, I would want to return `'gmail'` with frequency `2`.

To do this, I thought it would be a good idea to go through the array and discard everything occurring before the `@` and just keep the domains as a new array, which I could then iterate over. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your emails are `string`, you can do something like this:

```
emails = ["Johndoe@gmail.com", "Johndoe@yahoo.com", "Johndoe@aol.com", "Johndoe@someuni.xyz.com", "Janedoe@gmail.com"]
counts = Hash.new(0)
emails.each { |t| counts[t.partition("@").last] += 1}
counts #{"gmail.com"=>2, "yahoo.com"=>1, "aol.com"=>1, "someuni.xyz.com"=>1}
```

Comment: You can combine it to `counts = emails.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |t, h| ... }`

Comment: Thanks! if I then wanted to sort information based on the integer number, how would I do it? For example if I did `counts.sort`  (taken from the same counts you used), I get an output like `[gmail.com, 2], [yahoo.com, 1]..` which will be ordered alphabetically. I want ordered numerically, in other words ordered by emails with the highest frequency

Comment: Never mind, it seems to have worked using `counts.sort_by{ |a,b| b.to_i}`

Comment: Is there a way to format the ouput as a column instead of a list? So instead of 
`[gmail.com, 2], [yahoo.com, 1]..` it's outputted as a column

Comment: Yes, you can do something like this: `counts.each { |key, value| printf "%-20s %s\n", key, value }`

Answer (score 3):

Similar to mudasobwa's answer.

```
emails
.group_by{|s| s.partition("@").last}
.map{|k, v| [k, v.length]}
.max_by(&:last)
# => ["gmail.com", 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
emails.map { |e| e.split('@').last } # leave domains
      .group_by { |s| s }            # group
      .map { |k, v| [k, v.count] }   # count
      .sort_by(&:last)               # sort
      .last                          # get results
#⇒ ["gmail.com", 2]
```

Comment: It is funny that the only answer that provides the expected result (“I would want to return 'gmail' with frequency 2”) gets downvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

> I thought it would be a good idea to [...] just keep the domains as a new array, which I could then iterate over. How would I do this?

You should use a proper library to parse the email addresses, for example the [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem. It comes with a utility class [`Mail::Address`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail/Address) that provides easy access to the address fields:

```
require 'mail'

emails = %w[
  Johndoe@gmail.com
  Johndoe@yahoo.com
  Johndoe@aol.com
  Johndoe@someuni.xyz.com
  Janedoe@gmail.com
]

domains = emails.map { |email| Mail::Address.new(email).domain }
#=> ["gmail.com", "yahoo.com", "aol.com", "someuni.xyz.com", "gmail.com"]
```

It can also handle more complex address formats. From the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail%2FAddress%3Ainitialize):

```
a = Address.new('Mikel Lindsaar (My email address) <mikel@test.lindsaar.net>')
a.format       #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net> (My email address)'
a.address      #=> 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
a.display_name #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar'
a.local        #=> 'mikel'
a.domain       #=> 'test.lindsaar.net'
a.comments     #=> ['My email address']
a.to_s         #=> 'Mikel Lindsaar <mikel@test.lindsaar.net> (My email address)'
```